# Legenda or documentation for the mypy html report?

Tags: python, mypy

The mypy html report created with the `--html-report` option shows the type checked source code with green, yellow, and red background colours. It also shows tooltips when hovering over yellow and red lines, saying things like "Any Types on this line: Unannotated (x1)", "Any Types on this line: Explicit (x6) Unannotated (x2)", and "Any Types on this line: Omitted Generics (x3)".

Is there documentation that explains what this all means? I haven't been able to find it at https://mypy.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the details about the same in below link

https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/56ed5c36c2320eff96077d77ae7115bef60233ea/test-data/unit/reports.test

**Unannotated**

```py
def a(x) -> None:  # Unannotated
    any_f(x)
```

**Omitted generics**

```py
def b() -> List:  # Omitted Generics
    return [1, 2, 3]
```

Basically, type is given as list but not the element types inside the list

**Explicit**

```
def any_f(x: Any) -> None:  # Explicit
    pass

x: Any = 2  # Explicit
```

You are explicitly saying the type is `Any`

The `(x6)` basically refers to the count of instances